# compute relative percent of binned data

Tags: r

I have a data where I want to calculate the relative percent of column `tag` contained in the data in every `bin` and plot it as stacked bar plot.

```
df <- data.frame(tag = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "d", "b", "a"), 
                 tag_id = c(12, 45, 12, 43, 50, 50, 45, 12),
                 value = c(40, 11, 40, 12, 20, 22, 27, 29))

break_label <- c(10,20,30,40)

tag_label <- c("10-20","20-30", "30-40")

df$bin <- cut(df$value,breaks = break_label,labels = tag_label)
```

So in this case for `b, c, and d` in bin `10-20` would be 33.3% each and 0% for `a`.
How can I compute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may also use `prop.table` + `table` in `base R`

```
prop.table(table(df[c('tag', 'bin')]), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, reliant upon reshaping the data twice in order to fill non-existent entries with 0

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    count(tag, bin) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = bin, 
                values_from = n, 
                values_fill = 0) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -tag) %>%
    group_by(tag) %>%
    mutate(perc_n = value/sum(value))

 #   tag   name  value perc_n
 # 1 a     20-30     1  0.333
 # 2 a     30-40     2  0.667
 # 3 a     10-20     0  0    
 # 4 b     20-30     1  0.5 
 # ...
```